# Creating list of file types for git to ignore

Tags: git

If you want to create a list of file types that Git should ignore, then you should put that information in a file with what name?

Comment: Use `.gitignore` for this.

Answer (score 1):

-Navigate to your project -Type `touch .gitignore`

the `.gitignore` file will be created for you.

If you want predefined list of files, you can use
https://www.gitignore.io/ to search for specific language.

Answer (score 0):

```
.gitignore
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

> To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git rm --cached.